# Sticky footer isn't working

Tags: html, css

I just need a sticky footer for my mobile ui. (not fixed) I did a research and played with these codes.

**Main div**

```
.public-profile {
    background-color: #30b29e;
    max-width: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Footer**

```
.pulic-profile-score {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2ba08e;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

As you can see it's not stayed at the bottom of the page. It's placing on main div bottom area and showing white space area. I'm confused. I already gave 100% height to the main div but it's not placing on bottom of the page. If I change it to fixed, it shows white gap between footer and content area. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question as well

Answer (score 1):

Try min-height:100%; in .public-profile

Answer (score 0):

you would need to change position from `absolute` to `fixed`

Comment: If I change it to fixed, it shows white gap between footer and content area. See my updated description.

Comment: Can't you change the background-colorof the body to the light-green? Would that not solve your problem? Add padding-bottom to margin the same height as the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:sticky`, but be aware of it's current [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0):

On this class add these

```
.pulic-profile-score { 
position: fixed;
min-height:10%;// 10% of the main Div
}
```